# How to append html div to a table in response to jQuery getJSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to do the following:

```
$.getJSON("script/course_session.php", data, function(data) {
$.each(data, function(i, item) {

  var $tr = $('<tr>').append(
        $('<td>').text(item.start_date + " - " + item.end_date),
        $('<td>').text(
          '<div class=&quot;col-md-3 btn-buy animated fadeInRight&quot;><a href=&quot;#&quot; class=&quot;btn-u btn-u-sm enroll-button&quot;><i class=&quot;fa fa-university&quot;></i> Register</a></div>')
      ).appendTo("#session-table");
});
});
```

The intent being to achieve something like the following (I'm using Bootstrap):

[image]

However, this is how it gets printed:
[image]

What is the correct way to render html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use .html(...) instead of .text(). And " instead of quot;

Answer (score -1):

## [.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html-htmlString)

```
A string of HTML to set as the content of each matched element.
```

## [.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text-text)

```
The text to set as the content of each matched element. When Number or Boolean is supplied, it will be converted to a String representation.
```

The difference is the `.html(str)` will convert `str` the to a DOM if the `str` have a tag content and the `.text()` must convert `str` to a text even if `str` contains XML or html.